# Debug logging of ResponseBody by Springframework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging

I have a scenario where I send some sensitive data in the ResponseBody of a spring controller. Spring logs the entire response body in DEBUG mode, where I can see the sensitive data also. Now if I configure my app to print only INFO logs or higher, this won't be displayed, but that is not a fool proof method, since its possible that DEBUG mode could be turned on accidentally.

Is there anyway I can disable certain fields in the response body from being logged by Spring?

Thanks

Comment: I think that you can't control spring's logging level of response body. If you want certain fields to be disabled during logging just enable INFO log or higher as you suggest and then in the controller log only the information that you need without sensitive data.

Comment: You should be able to switch off logging for the particular class that worries you.  Just add a new logger with the same name as the fully qualified class name and set the log level for the logger to `OFF`.  Then, even if the log level for the rest of the application is changed to `DEBUG`, the concerned class will never print any messages to the logs.  We have done this for Atomikos and Freemarker logs in our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be that you implement a custom converter for logback (if that is your logging library)
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier

It enables you to convert your logging data and blur out any data that should be removed from the message.
From the documentation it is pretty straight forward

```
public class MySampleConverter extends ClassicConverter {

  long start = System.nanoTime();

  @Override
  public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
    long nowInNanos = System.nanoTime();
    return Long.toString(nowInNanos-start);
  }
}
```

And the config

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="nanos" 
                  converterClass="chapters.layouts.MySampleConverter" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-6nanos [%thread] - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

If you're using Log4j you can implement a custom filter which would mask the data per your layout
http://vozis.blogspot.sg/2012/02/log4j-filter-to-mask-payment-card.html

Edit
The final easier solution turned out to be to override toString of the return object. Spring uses toString to log the return message

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using Log4j as my logging framework. I will try out implementing the Log4j filter. Can I mask the data for a particular field rather than checking for the data itself? For example if the field name of the class is password, I would have to mask the data.

Comment: How are you currently logging the ResponsBody? Are you using a filter or built in Spring logging appenders?

Comment: I am not explicitly logging the response body, so it should be the built in Spring logging appenders.

Comment: So looking at the code it should be enough that you override toString on your sensitive objects..  `if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
       logger.debug("Written [" + returnValue + "] as \"" + selectedMediaType + "\" using [" +
         messageConverter + "]");
      }` is using a toString on the return value which is whatever you sent back from the controller

Comment: I was passing a map in the response body. I wrapped the response in a pojo class and returned it after overriding toString as I needed. That fixed the issue. Thank you !